# Trigger has mutating error when insert

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle11g

I am having an issue with a trigger. After I add the trigger to my database, when I try to insert a row that the trigger will act on, I get a mutating table error. I don't know how to avoid this. Would someone mind looking at this and tell me what I am doing wrong, and how to rewrite it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ORNG_INV_LINE_TOTAL_TRIGGER
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON ORNG_INV_LINE
COMPOUND TRIGGER 
AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN 
UPDATE ORNG_INVOICE SET Inv_Amount = (SELECT SUM(ORNG_INV_LINE.Inv_Line_Total) 
FROM ORNG_INV_LINE
WHERE ORNG_INVOICE.INV_Num = :NEW.INV_Num);
END AFTER EACH ROW;
END ORNG_INV_LINE_TOTAL_TRIGGER;
/
```

I'm not sure why it is triggering an error. I'm trying to do the action after the update. All I want to do is get the sum for all of the lines of all matching invoice numbers, and write that value in the INVOICE table. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is written on the table ORNG_INV_LINE for insert or update and again you made a select on the same table while updating ORNG_INVOICE table so trigger is mutating,
to over come this you have to use statement level trigger instead of row level trigger .
i.e after each statement should be there in code instead of after each row.
This can help you.

Comment: Sorry about the below post, I didn't see this when I posted my answer. Using a statement level trigger was correct, as seen below. I appreciate you looking at it...I'm still not getting the hang of this crap, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution...apparently everyone is busy with Thanksgiving. Hopefully this helps the next guy.

```
create or replace TRIGGER ORNG_INV_L_TTL_TRIG
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ORNG_INV_LINE
BEGIN
UPDATE ORNG_INVOICE SET Inv_Amount = (SELECT SUM(Inv_Line_Total) 
FROM ORNG_INV_LINE
WHERE INV_Num = ORNG_INVOICE.INV_Num);
END ORNG_INV_L_TTL_TRIG;
/
```